# How do I stop autotools from adding command line options?

Tags: c++, autotools

In my source directory, I type `make main.o`, which issues the command:

```
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -Wno-write-strings -O0 -g -g -O2 -MT main.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/main.Tpo -c -o main.o main.cc
mv -f .deps/main.Tpo .deps/main.Po
```

Some of this was created by me (`-std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -Wno-write-strings -O0 -g`) and some of it wasn't (`-g -O2 -MT main.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/main.Tpo`)

**Q1**: How do I tell autotools to stop inserting `-g -O2`?

**Q2**: What's the deal with `-MT main.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/main.Tpo`? Is it necessary? Unnecessary? Can I get rid of it? If so, how?

**Q3**: How do I add to `AM_CXXFLAGS` via m4 macros seemlessly? The approach I have adopted so far is to define the macro `m4/ax_debug.m4` as follows:

```
AC_DEFUN([AX_DEBUG], [


AC_ARG_WITH([debug],
  [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-debug], [Enable debug (default is no)])],
  [with_debug=$withval],
  [with_debug=no])


AM_CONDITIONAL([WITH_DEBUG], [test "x$with_debug" = "xyes"])

AS_IF([test "x$with_debug" = "xyes"], [
  AC_SUBST([DEBUG_CXXFLAGS], ["-O0 -g"])
])

AC_MSG_NOTICE([checking if debugging required ... $with_debug])

])dnl AX_DEBUG
```

and to use those flags within `src/Makefile.am` as follows:

```
AM_CXXFLAGS = ... $(DEBUG_CXXFLAGS)
```

Is there a way I can arrange it so that `DEBUG_CXXFLAGS`is added automatically?

**Update (with possible answers):** In regards to Q1, the [answer](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/C_002b_002b-Compiler.htmlhttp://) appears to be to add the following line to `configure.ac` after `AC_INIT(...)`:

```
: ${CXXFLAGS=""}
```

and delete `$(DEBUG_CXXFLAGS)` from `src/Makefile.am`.

In regards to Q2, I still have no idea what that's about.

In regards to Q3, the answer would appear to be to write

```
AC_SUBST([CXXFLAGS], ["$CXXFLAGS -O0 -g"])
```

instead of

```
AC_SUBST([DEBUG_CXXFLAGS], ["-O0 -g"])
```

I'm not sure if that's an "official" solution though.

Comment: Maybe it is inserting options present in environment variables? Why are you using `-fpermissive` btw?

Comment: @VTT I am working on a legacy C project, and converting it to C++. C++ baulks unless I use `-fpermissive`. The cleanup is a long process, so it's important that the project compiles rather than refusing to do so.

Comment: Have you considered dropping autotools and switching to some modern build system?

Comment: @VTT I've toyed around with things like `cmake` in the past, but couldn't get very far with it. In the end I decided that `autotools` was the way to go. It's standard, and doesn't required any dependencies. I go along with the philosophy that "autotools is the worst build system there is, except for all the others".

Comment: I can only answer Q2: These Flags are telling GCC to output the dependencies of the compilation unit to a file which will then be included (possibly after preprocessing) by the Makefile, such that it always correctly recompiles. For more information, see http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/